# 'function' object is not subscriptable in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a tower in Python with a plugin called kehpri that lets me code to autocad.

I've got a list of lists (which I've called `lista_caminhos`). Each item is a list of points that make up a path.

I'm trying to do a recursion that makes a spline through each item on the list of lists.

I am not able to.

```
    def lista_caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista):
         return matriz_transposta (piso_pisos_rodados (lista (p,a), n_andares, p, a, a_torcao))

    def caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista, lista_caminhos):
        if lista_caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista) == []:
            pass
        else:
            spline (lista_caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista)[0])
            caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista, lista_caminhos[1:])
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `lista_caminhos` is a function, not a list.

Comment: The error message you omitted should point to `lista_caminhos[1:]`, which is invalid because functions cannot be subscripted.

Comment: Keep in mind that functions and values share a namespace in python, so the `lista_caminhos` parameter to the `caminhos` function shadows the top-level `lista_caminhos` function.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line, you are trying to slice the function `lista_caminhos` instead of the list it returns. Adding parentheses should fix this to operate on the return value rather than the function.

```
def lista_caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista):
     return matriz_transposta (piso_pisos_rodados (lista (p,a), n_andares, p, a, a_torcao))

def caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista, lista_caminhos):
    if lista_caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista) == []:
        pass
    else:
        spline (lista_caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista)[0])
        caminhos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares, lista, lista_caminhos()[1:])
```

Comment: I was careful with the distinction between function and list and it worked! Thanks for the help!